# Button object onto a label

Tags: html, css, vimeo

Currently I have a video that I have within an object tag, this video from Vimeo and I pick what I intend to place a button created by me right above this video and to place it where I want, I've got absolutely positioned, but of course, when I resized the page completely out of position :s any solution?

This is the CSS:

```
width: 204px;
height: 65px;
z-index: 1;
position:absolute;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cd8228;
border-radius: 3px 3px;
float:right;
margin-right: 20px;
```

what I would like is to give a margin to the right and down and this is the video respetadado beneath

Comment: Post the code please?

Comment: Put on the question the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set position: relative to button container.

```
.container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
.button{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    right: 20px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Also when you use position: absolute, to set the element position use top, bottom, left, right properties instead of margins or floats.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5ecdV/